# How can Change the number of port block programmatically in matlab ??(simulink)

Tags: matlab, simulink

I wanna add one port to revolute block programmatically, i know we can change it by change " Number of sensor / actuator ports:",but i need to change it by programmatically .
What should i do ?

Comment: What is " revolute block" ?

Comment: @P0W It's a SimMechanics block, see http://uk.mathworks.com/help/physmod/sm/mech/ref/revolute.html (1st generation) and http://uk.mathworks.com/help/physmod/sm/ref/revolutejoint.html (2nd generation)

Comment: @am304 can u help me ??  i should do it but i dont know how i can change it.

Comment: Which block are you talking about? The first or second generation one?

Comment: Sorry, the best I can recommend is put the block in a model, select it and in the MATLAB command window try `get_param(gcb,'<block_property>')` where `<block_property>` is one of the properties of the block. You can use tab completion once you have typed the first quotation mark to go through all the block properties for this block. Try and figure out which one you need to change with `set_param` (those starting with `Mask...` are probably a good bet).

Comment: @am304 this way doesn't work, i couldn't do that , did u taste it ?i actually i wanna change number of port revolute block (first generation) . i wanna have 2 inputs and 1 output for that block . i tasted your direction and matlab says " Revolute block (mask) does not have a parameter named '<block_property>' "

Comment: I don't have access to Simulink anymore, so can't test it unfortunately. But the only way to change block parameters programmatically is through set_param.

Comment: @am304 I had same problem with environment  machine port  i could solve this way `add_block('mylibtwolink/Ground','simtwolink/Ground','ShowEnvPort','on')`  .but for this issue i cant do that like this command .

Comment: fortunately ,i can solve this problem , i make a new model in simulink and add revolute block then change number of port to 1 (2 inputs and 1 output) ,i make a Library and add that block in my own library then call that block in m file.Note that you should unlock your Library , it works but i think there is way that we can change number of sensor.